Помогите допилить миксин
Есть вот такой универсальный миксин для формы. Он должен выводить ошибку, если юзер, при изменении данных, введет уже занятое имя, но если введет свое же имя, то форма должна его пропустить.
class UniqueNameErrorMixin:
def clean_name(self):

    name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
    current_obj = self._meta.model.objects.filter(name=name).first()
    if current_obj and name != current_obj.name:
        raise ValidationError(
            f'{self._meta.model._meta.verbose_name}\
            с таким именем уже существует.')
    return name

Проблема в том, что нужный текст ошибки мне он выдает если я уберу условие после AND.
А если все оставить все как есть, то ошибка стандартная. Например "Статус с таким Имя уже существует."
